# Lookup Values in Power Pivot tables with DAX

Tags: excel, lookup, powerpivot, dax

i am trying to create a calculated column in Excel which should contain values from related tables. I tried looking into the Lookup function but this looks too complicated for my knowledge.

I have an **Incident** table where i want to have a calculated Column named **closdBy**. In this column i want to put the name of the operator that closed the incident. Every incident has many mutation entries which are stored in a **Mutations** table. This Mutations table has 1 **statusID** which comes from another related table named **Status**

In the calculated Field **closedBy** i want the calculated column to display the **Name** of the operator whose name matches the **statusID** **Closed** The name of the operator comes from the **Operator** table.

Anyone can help me with this ? Would appreciate it a lot.

[image: Tables]

POWER BI Example: https://ufile.io/z0g4x

Excel Example: https://ufile.io/6adju

Comment: hi Please provide some sample data so that will try to resolve it

Comment: it seems that the data model needs some adjustment:  (1) add an "incidentID" column to the Mutations table; (2) rename the "mutationID" column in the Incident table to "incidentID", which is related to the same-named column in the Mutations table

Comment: I have added the sample data here:

https://ufile.io/6adju

So in power pivot i want to add the correct values for Resolved by and Closed by

Comment: @DAX0110 I understand what you pointed out but it shouldn't make a big diffrence. I just renamed mutationID to incidentID

Comment: I have also added a Power BI file in the original post

Answer (score 1):

**required result in incident table ([download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mqP6A0JP_dhe4a4F6w6iOTr9G2DnA5s8/view?usp=sharing) PowerBI file) :**

[image]

I have made some **modification in relationship between table** incident and mutation

**created a column in mutation table** 
ID_Closed = IF(Mutation[statusID]="{CLO}",Mutation[ID],CONCATENATE(Mutation[ID],Mutation[statusID]))

[image]

[image]

Hoping this will help!

Comment: Hi, this ok for one field, but what if i want to have values in Resolved by too ? And what if there are more entries that could have status RESOLVED for example and that i only want to display the name  next to the newest date ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how my table looks like. The mutation table can have the same value for status (see {CLO} but I want to have the field Closed By and Resolved by in the Incident table to display the most recent Operator.

I have here an adjusted PowerBi file with more data:
https://ufile.io/20u0v

[image]